# JS function addEventListener on keypress adding text with innerHtml is running exponentially each time I use it

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener, innerhtml, keypress

I'm actually learning since two month so excuse-me if it seems really dumb when I'm asking this question but : Why is my function is running exponentially each time I use it?

```
const textArea = document.querySelector('.messenger__text-area')
const input = document.querySelector('.messenger__input')

function addText() {
input.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        textArea.innerHTML += `<div class='message__sent'>${input.value}</div>`
        input.value = null   
    }
 });
}
```

I'm working on chatroom and I just want this div to be displayed in the text area, which works, kinda but each time I press enter to send the input value into the text are it makes too much copy of the empty div "message__sent". Seems like if I put more letter, more "phantom" divs are created.

I just want it to be created one single time when I press enter, how do you think I could do that?

Thanks for your answers, I really couldn't find anything on the internet to help me so here I am.

(i'll share the html with you below so you can feel free to test if you want)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Afpa'car Chatroom</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../index.css">
</head>

<body>
<header>Header</header>
<div class="hr-large--grey"></div>
<main>
    <div class="messenger">
        <div class="messenger__contact">
            <div class="messenger__contact--return">
                <a href="../index.html">
                    <
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="messenger__contact--name">
                <h2>
                    Placeholder Contact
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="messenger__contact--status">
                ●
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="hr-large" />
        <div class="messenger__text-area">
            Placeholder Text
        </div>
        <hr class="hr-large" />
        <input class='messenger__input' onkeypress='addText()' placeholder="Ecrivez un message..."></input>
    </div>
</main>
<div class="hr-large--grey"></div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
<script src="../index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You add the eventListener for EVERY execution of the addText. remove `onkeypress='addText()'` and remove the wrapped function so you just have `input.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) { if (e.keyCode === 13) { textArea.innerHTML += \`<div class='message__sent'>${input.value}</div>\`  input.value = null ;  } });`

Comment: Your addText funtion call is bound to onkeypress and in the addText function you attach a new listener every time the function is called. So every time the user presses a key, a new event listener is created, making the event fire multiple times. Remove the onkeypress attribute and call addText once somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your quick answers! It indeed worked, I feel kinda silly haha.
I still have a lot to learn, thanks again for your help!